# 'challenges' or 'challenge'

Tags: grammar

I have two questions.

1. Should I use 'challenges' or 'challenge' in this text?
2. Should I use article 'the' or 'a' before 'criteria'?

> That is why firms attach great importance to the possibility of using
>   integrated system. But the key **challenges** for people designing
>   solutions for manufacture applications is a complete lack of **a**
>   **criteria** and requirements.

Comment: Refine the whole paragraph. It does not look proper.

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but in the first sentence, it could be "an/the integrated system" or "integrated systems". Maybe you can tell in context but I can't. Also it should be *manufacturing* applications*.

Comment: I would rewrite it like this: *That is why firms **recognize** the importance **of** the possibility of using integrated **systems**. But the key **challenge** for people designing solutions for **manufacturing** applications is **the** complete lack **of criteria** and requirements.*

Answer (score 2):

I'm still not fully convinced with the paragraph (many flaws). But, since you asked particularly about those words and the articles, I'm addressing that so that to clarify that *in general*. Maybe, you take care of this in future then.

In this case, you are talking about the challenge of **[lacking](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/lack_1)** something (the word *[lack](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/lack_1)* in your sentence is used as a **singular and countable**). Thus, it's the *challenge* and not *two or more* challenges!

In any case, *[criteria](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/criterion?q=criteria)* will not have *a*, it's plural. The singular will be criterion.

Answer (score 1):

Re 1:

```
But the key challenge for people [...] is
```

Since `key` and `is` are singular, their noun, `challenge` had better be as well.

Re 2:

```
a complete lack of criteria and requirements.
```

`criteria` is plural, so takes no article here.

Additionally, though you didn't ask, `manufacture` is incorrect, and you probably want `manufacturing`.

Comment: Like most adjectives, *key* is unmarked for number.  It would be okay with plural *challenges*: "What **are** the key **challenges** you face as a producer?"

Comment: @snailplane, quite right, my mistake!  Serves me right for posting after my bedtime.